# JNDI and resource refrencing

Tags: java

When accessing a resource from the JNDI do you have to prefix the lookup with    `java:/comp/env/`

Is there any rules when to prefix or when not to prefix?

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, it depends on how the resource is defined in your web server's context.xml.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

In my web.xml file I have a resource-ref of mail/Session. This is then linked to a real resource through jetty-env.xml or weblogic.xml

Comment: Shouldn't it be consistent regardless of servlet container?

Comment: I think I misread your question. I was thinking the datasource definition. "comp" is the binding at the root of the namespace. You can create multiple new bindings to comp. "env" is the component's environment-related bindings, and I believe tomcat uses this binding as it's default context descriptor. So, yes, if you are using a tomcat server, you will have to declare where it's default context descriptor is (comp/env).

Comment: It seems that this is inconsistent across application servers.